# How to properly use object path in Golang Swagger?

Tags: go, swagger

I am using swag in Golang. I am wondering how to accurately select and use multiple dataClasses in a similar path. It is exactly described in the example below.

There are 3 dataClasses in my code

```
   1. ../dataClass/v1/auth/res/createUser.go  <<<< i want use this in swag doc
   2. ../dataClass/v2/auth/res/createUser.go
   3. ../dataClass/v1/file/res/createUser.go
```

There is one api as below. In this api example, I want to use dataClass number 1 indicated above in the line of @success 200 {object} res.UserCreateRes, but the path is duplicated.

```
// @Summary 게스트 유저를 생성합니다
// @Description 게스트 유저를 생성합니다.
// @Tags 회원
// @Accept json
// @Produce json
// @Success 200 {object} res.UserCreateRes <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
// @Failure 400 {object} common.DetaultError
// @Router /v1/auth/guestRegister [post]
```

I want to represent exactly the dataClass I want, but I don't know how to do it. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

`swag` looks for package instead of filepath. In this case all dataClasses are in package named `res` and they all share the same name `createUser`.
`swag` cannot resolve the duplicated resources and probably return `cannot find type definition: res.UserCreateRes`.

A workaround is to customize the [display name](https://github.com/swaggo/swag/blob/master/README.md#rename-model-to-display) per each dataClass

```
../dataClass/v1/auth/res/createUser.go
type UserCreateRes struct {} //@name v1.res.createUserRes

../dataClass/v2/auth/res/createUser.go
type UserCreateRes struct {}//@name v2.res.createUserRes
```

In the API annotation:

```
// @Success 200 {object} v1.res.createUserRes
```